# OSX 10.8 has libpng compatibility 27. Mavericks has 25. What is going on?

Tags: macos

I am trying to compile an application on 10.8, and it binds to a libpng15.15 library that, according to otool, has compatibility version 27. The library is located in /opt/X11/lib

```
$ otool -L libpng15.15.dylib 
libpng15.15.dylib:
    /opt/X11/lib/libpng15.15.dylib (compatibility version 27.0.0, current version 27.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

Now, when I try to copy my executable to another mac and run it, I get a message that this mac libpng provides version 25.0.0, and thus can't run. The library is in /usr/X11/lib. This mac was a 10.6.8, it's not a developer machine, and was upgraded to 10.9 with the Apple Store download.

How is it possible that a 10.9 has a libpng compatibility version lower than 10.8?

Edit: I discovered that probably it's due to the fact that I need header files for the X11 libraries, so I installed XQuartz. However, XQuartz also upgrades the libraries with a  higher compatibility version. This does not introduce any problem for the local system, but when I have to deploy on Mavericks it won't work, unless I install XQuartz there as well. Is there a better way to solve this problem, short of copying the header files manually?

Comment: Why not just link to `libpng` (i.e. not version-specific)?

Comment: @trojanfoe: it's matplotlib that is actually deciding what to bind on. I might hack it but in any case it should work. It's the difference in compatibility version that puzzles me.

Comment: Well if you were using something from `/opt` then that's not a standard library.  Is this an `.app` you are building (if so, you can probably bundle all necessary libraries with it)?

Comment: @trojanfoe: I think that OSX installed it in opt when I installed the X development. /usr/X11 is a link that points to /opt/X11 on 10.8. This is also another thing I don't understand

Comment: @trojanfoe: yes I am building an app and I could probably just copy the libpng in there, it's just that I assume I will have the same problem with a lot of other libraries, and I would have to copy all of them... which is kind of annoying

Comment: I don't know anything about X11 under OSX.  Yeah I would imagine that is the case.  Not to mention you have to change the "install_name" of each library within the app binary so it looks for those libraries within `../Frameworks`.  It's not trivial developing for OSX :(

Answer (score 3):

If you have a symlink from `/usr/X11` to `/opt/X11`, then you have most likely installed something using a third-party installer (brew or ports?) that has taken over your Apple-installed `/usr/X11` location. Apple doesn't create, much less add anything into `/opt`, and it certainly doesn't put the X11 binaries or libraries there.

So, you are basically running 2 different environments on those machines, the 10.6.8 machine which has had system binaries overridden by a third-party installer, and a 10.9(.1?) machine which has not had these overridden.

Checking on existing, clean (i.e. no X11 ports installed), Apple developer tools installed  versions of 10.9.1 and 10.6.8 that I'm currently running, I see the following:

10.6.8:

- /usr/X11/lib/libpng12.0.dylib (compatibility version 47.0.0, current version 47.0.0)
- /usr/X11/lib/libpng.3.dylib (compatibility version 50.0.0, current version 50.0.0)

10.9.1:

- /usr/X11/lib/libpng12.0.dylib (compatibility version 48.0.0, current version 48.0.0)
- /usr/X11/lib/libpng.3.dylib (compatibility version 51.0.0, current version 51.0.0)
- /usr/X11/lib/libpng15.15.dylib (compatibility version 25.0.0, current version 25.0.0)

For thoroughness, I checked our clean installs of 10.7 and 10.8, which were both:

- /usr/X11/lib/libpng12.0.dylib (compatibility version 47.0.0, current version 47.0.0)
- /usr/X11/lib/libpng.3.dylib (compatibility version 50.0.0, current version 50.0.0)
- /usr/X11/lib/libpng15.15.dylib (compatibility version 20.0.0, current version 20.0.0)

My suggestion would be to rebuild if you can on a machine which doesn't have `/usr/X11` patched out, or (if that's not a possibility), consider the possibility of installing the same overrides on the target that have been done on the source.

Comment: You provide superb answers, my friend.

Comment: That's what I suspected. port messed up my system. Is there any way of reverting to the old, system provided libpng/X11 without a full reinstall? As far as I can see, they are no longer there.

Comment: You could try copying from a known-good installation of 10.6.8, or applying the non-delta update for 10.6.8 and seeing if that fixes things, or if you have an old backup, you could try that.

Comment: I have the suspect that it wasn't macports, but XQuartz. OSX 10.8 ships with /usr/X11/lib and all the libs, but there are no headers. To get the headers I installed XQuartz, but that ruins the development environment as it also upgrades libpng (I suspect among others) meaning that what I produce depend on Xquartz as well. Do you know how to deploy headers without ruining the basic development layout and compatibility version of 10.8?

Comment: @StefanoBorini Unfortunately I do not. That makes sense that it would be the problem, and there may be no option other than installing XQuartz as a pre-requisite.

Comment: @gaige: I can't ask my customers to install XQuartz, so that's not an option. I guess that the only remaining choice is to ship XQuartz libraries as private libraries within my .app. How do others do it? Why doesn't Apple provide the headers?

Comment: @StefanoBorini: You'd have to check with binaries that are shipped of that kind.  I don't write X11 code (not in years), but have no direct experience shipping product for OS X in this form.   As for why Apple doesn't provide the headers, I'd imagine because they don't want to support X11 any more than necessary.